# Accessing secure Ignite cluster from spark and api

Tags: apache-spark, ignite

I have enabled security on ignite cluster. I started with basic security following the ignite documentation.

https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/advanced-security

I added the following configuration in my xml with persistence enabled

```
<property name="authenticationEnabled" value="true"/>
```

It created a super user with ignite as user and password.

I have an api which reads data from Ignite Index

```
IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();
cfg.setClientMode(true);
TcpDiscoverySpi discoSpi = new TcpDiscoverySpi();
TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder vmIpFinder = new TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder();
vmIpFinder.setAddresses(Arrays.asList("localhost"));
cfg.setDiscoverySpi(discoSpi);
cfg.setAuthenticationEnabled(true);
ignite = Ignition.start(cfg);
```

I couldn't find any method in IgniteConfiguration class which accepts user credentials. How do I authenticate my client connection

Also I am writing a spark dataframe to ignite.

```
df.write.format(FORMAT_IGNITE).option(OPTION_CONFIG_FILE,"default-config.xml")
    .option(OPTION_TABLE, "sampleTable")
    .option(OPTION_CREATE_TABLE_PRIMARY_KEY_FIELDS, "PK")
    .option(OPTION_STREAMER_ALLOW_OVERWRITE, "true")
    .mode(saveMode).save()
```

How do I authenticate my spark application to write to ignite.

I couldn't find any online resources. Any help is appreciated.Thanks!!

Comment: I guess that it's because you didn't implement the GridSecurityProcessor 
 as described here: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/advanced-security#section-authorization. Without this processor, only thin clients can be authenticated.

Comment: Thanks @AndreiAleksandrov. Also I have read when writing from spark, the ignite api doesn't use thin client. So if I implement GridSecurityProcessor, how do I authorize spark.

Comment: I can only suggest you to take a look here http://smartkey.co.uk/development/securing-an-apache-ignite-cluster. You should have two parts inside - credential provider and authenticator.  Also, you can try to use the ready to go solution like next - https://docs.gridgain.com/docs/security-and-audit.